# Exponent not allowed in defining variable?

Tags: vba, excel

I have simple VBA program which creates truth table. These lines are in red (some kind of syntax error):

```
 end0=2^power/2
```

And

```
end1=2^power
```

Here they are in context:

```
Sub filltruthtable()
cases = 2 * inputnum
Dim power
power = inputnum - colcounter
Dim end0
end0=2^power/2
Dim start1
start1 = end0 + 1
Dim end1
end1=2^power
For counterrow = 1 To inputnum
    For counterrow = 1 To end0
        Cells(counterrow, countercol).Value = 0
    Next
    For counterrow = start1 To end1
        Cells(counterrow, countercol).Value = 0
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you adjust that code so it will at least compile? The `counterrow` var is used in a For ..  Next within another For ... Next that increments `counterrow` as well.

Comment: I did just copy the line in my VBA for EXCEL2013, qhich automagically added spaces, like that : "end1 = 2 ^ power". It compiled & worked. As Jeeped said, check your loops first, using the same variable in two nested fors means looking for trouble. When I disable them, the rest of the code runs.

Answer (score 0):

Exponent is allowed in defining variables but you have to make sure that it is actually a number and not a string containing a number.

I've declared all variables used in filltruthtable() as long integers but that's simply because I do not know what kind of numbers you'll be using or if you've declared the variables with a public or module scope.

also when giving value to variables I'll always make sure that the value is in the kind I want, for example

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim Demo_Num As Integer
    Demo_Num = CInt(Application.InputBox ("Please give an input.", "Input")
end sub
```

Now the Demo_Num is a long integer and can be used as an exponent.

```
Sub filltruthtable()

    Dim cases As Long, Dim inputnum As Long, Dim power As Long, 
    Dim end0 As Long, Dim start1 As Long, Dim end1 As Long, 
    Dim colcounter As Long, Dim counterrow As Long, Dim countercol As Long

    cases = 2 * inputnum
    power = inputnum - colcounter
    end0 = 2 ^ power / 2
    start1 = end0 + 1
    end1 = 2 ^ power

    For counterrow = 1 To inputnum
        For counterrow = 1 To end0
            Cells(counterrow, countercol).Value = 0
        Next
        For counterrow = start1 To end1
            Cells(counterrow, countercol).Value = 0
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim counterrow1, counterrow2 As Integer` declares counterrow1 as variant and counterrow2 As Integer.  When working with rows and columns Declaring both as long would be better.  Also your other Dim Statement is the same, all but the last are declared as variant.  The last as an integer.  Which may be what you want.

Comment: The `Dim counterrow1, counterrow2 as integer` was just a remnant of me fiddling with it and I meant to change it back to Thomas Shera's original code. Truth be told I'm still fairly new to VBA and I'm learning by simply trying and trying again so my code may not be optimal and I might not yet understand the finer points of VBA.

Comment: Sorry if my comment came across as harsh, it was meant merely as information for you to do with as you please.  In vba, lining up the declaration like that does not do what your were thinking.  Dim counterrow1 as integer, counterrow2 as integer` would be proper.

Comment: Oh no, not at all, I was under the impression from the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ee5a7s1.aspx) website on the Dim function that I could declare multiple variables in one statement where the variables are separated by a comma. Your comment actually cleared up some issues I have had with a project I'm working on. So, thank you.